# Roboearth build fails at re_vision

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying to build roboearth on oneiric on electric version of ROS and using gcc4.6 compiler. but i came across with the following error:

> [ 19%] Building CXX object
> CMakeFiles/DUtilsCV.dir/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.o
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:
> In static member function ‘static void
> DUtilsCV::Drawing::drawCorrespondences(cv::Mat&,
> const cv::Mat&, const cv::Mat&, const
> std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, const
> std::vector<cv::KeyPoint>&, const
> std::vector&, const
> std::vector&)’:
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:107:35:
> error: taking address of temporary
> [-fpermissive]
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:116:3:
> error: taking address of temporary
> [-fpermissive]
> /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.cpp:124:3:
> error: taking address of temporary
> [-fpermissive]   make[3]: ***
> [CMakeFiles/DUtilsCV.dir/src/3rdparty/DUtilsCV/Drawing.o]
> Error 1   make[3]: Leaving directory
> `/home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/build' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DUtilsCV.dir/all] Error 2  make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/build'
> make[1]: *** [all] Error 2   make[1]:
> Leaving directory
> `/home/pragyan/tredext/biome/roboearth/re_vision/build'

Any body with clue what's the meaning of error: taking address of temporary[-fpermissive] and how it can be resolved? Thanks in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12029/roboearth-build-fails-at-re_vision/) by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2011-11-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of revision r1464, the RoboEarth object scanning software and re_vision should compile under Ubuntu Oneiric, too.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2011-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pntripathi9417](https://answers.ros.org/users/1369/pntripathi9417/) on 2011-11-30**:
thanks it is working fine now.